# What is the best scripting language to develop a database driven website?

Tags: scripting, frameworks

I'm planning to develop a database driven website. The database is really huge. I can't compare it to Wikipedia but may be it can be as huge as imdb.com. I'm in a dilemma as to what scripting language to opt for. With ruby on rails web development framework, its faster to write code, but is it good for managing a huge database and performance scalability etc come into picture, i'm not sure about RoR. Kindly suggest me a good web development framework for my project. If possible a comparison of your choice with other frameworks listing the pros and cons.

Comment: The size of the database might affect which DBMS you choose, but should have no effect whatsoever on language choice; they're all perfectly capable of doing SQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

I will like to answer this question in two parts.

**1. Database:** If your data is going to huge, Then your first focus will on designing the database  . Database driven development, always bottle neck by Database not by frame work. If you have time then try to explore database like,

- [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)
- [Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable)

Now Come on to second Point

**2. Framework/ Language:** Here almost all language will perform ~ same level, Here it depend on Design of database and what will be your end application. If going for webbased application, go for

- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Ruby on Rail](http://rubyonrails.org/)

If you are planing to develop application in many part (with multi-language) , like Scripting, Database Interface and web interface then,

1. Scripting : Perl/Python
2. Database Interface : C/C++
3. Web Interface : Django/ROR

Answer (score 2):

You could also use WebDNA, which is specifically designed to build database driven websites. It is a scripting language as well as a database system.

Answer (score 1):

Well the scripting language will only play into effect really if you have substantial numbers of users. However even then it depends on how you write your code, for Example Facebook uses PHP.

With a large database - it would be important to look at the RDBMS that you are using - and make sure that its going to cope with what you plan to do with it. Without this you are going to have a bottle neck before you even get to your apps tier.

What database are you using?

Comment: OK... and what sort of things are you going to be doing with the data? You mentioned Wikipedia / IMDB - are you expecting to build a webapp that has several million hits a month? What sort of volumes are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The user will likely have a user base of no people and only 2 items in the database. Most of these supposed web devs here are idiots and dont know what they are doing and have no business plan. They also have no brains